# How to check that each element of a list has a name?

Tags: r, list

I want a function `is_named_list(lst)` which returns true if all elements in the list have a name, and false otherwise. In the case where the list is empty, it should return false. What considerations do I need to account for while trying to write such a function. For example, a list with no names behaves differently to a list with incomplete names, with respect to the `names` function:

```
> tmp_list <- list(a = 1, b = 2, 3)
> names(tmp_list)
[1] "a" "b" "" # empty string for unnamed third element

> tmp_list <- list(1, 2, 3)
> names(tmp_list)
NULL # null value when no elements have names.
```

Answer (score 3):

Just compare the length of the list (`length(tmp_list)`) against the length of the names vector for that list (`length(names(tmp_list))`), where the names are *not* empty string.

```
all_names <- function(list) {
    return(length(list) == sum(names(list) != "", na.rm=TRUE))
}

> all_names(tmp_list)
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try

```
is_named_list <- function(lst) {
    !(is.null(names(lst))|any(!nzchar(names(lst))))
 }
is_named_list(tmp_list) 
#[1] FALSE
```

and for the second example

```
tmp_list <- list(1, 2, 3)
is_named_list(tmp_list)
#[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
is_named_list <- function(lst) {
    all(names(tmp_list) != "") & !is.null(names(tmp_list))
}

tmp_list <- list(a = 1, b = 2, 3)
is_named_list(tmp_list)
#FALSE
tmp_list <- list(1, 2, 3)
is_named_list(tmp_list)
#FALSE
tmp_list <- list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
is_named_list(tmp_list)
#TRUE
```